# How can factor analysis results in integer factor scores?

Tags: categorical-data, factor-analysis

I was given the results of a factor analysis performed on categorical variables. The factor analysis used consisted in a WLSMV method of estimation with the model fit applied to a tetrachoric matrix (with probit link function). The number of factors was determined with parallel analysis and the resulting factor loadings were as follows:

```
VARIABLES   FACTOR 1    FACTOR 2    FACTOR 3    FACTOR 4
VAR1    0.631   0.265   0.291   0.259
VAR2    0.524   0.134   0.111   0.16
VAR3    0.642   0.198   0.239   0.273
VAR4    0.547   0.205   0.194   0.216
VAR5    0.72    0.224   0.223   0.223
VAR6    0.536   0.133   0.1 0.081
VAR7    0.537   0.149   0.232   0.232
VAR8    0.485   0.11    0.097   0.147
VAR9    0.69    0.2 0.282   0.206
VAR10   0.505   0.139   0.185   0.184
VAR11   0.643   0.149   0.171   0.117
VAR12   0.557   0.139   0.317   0.29
VAR13   0.292   0.95    0.205   0.239
VAR14   0.269   0.917   0.248   0.266
VAR15   0.2 0.532   0.172   0.337
VAR16   0.379   0.303   0.629   0.289
VAR17   0.379   0.347   0.883   0.299
VAR18   0.334   0.192   0.95    0.374
VAR19   0.194   0.168   0.303   0.415
VAR20   0.24    0.238   0.205   0.693
VAR21   0.262   0.4 0.284   0.492
VAR22   0.242   0.159   0.249   0.795
VAR23   0.232   0.206   0.283   0.701
```

However there were no details on the method used to compute the factor scores shown below (and unfortunately this is not possible to get information on this method at this time).

The questionnaire was heavily biased towards non-informative answers (i.e. many subjects answering same answer [e.g. "I don't think so"] to ALL the questions). The factor scores have many zeros (somewhat expected considering the large number of subjects with exactly the same answers), but the most surprising element is that the factor scores are all integers (and non normally distributed, as can be found out from the data below).

In which possible context is this possible to have factor scores be exclusively integers? Please note that these scores would have most likely be generated with the Mplus software.

```
factor1_scores  factor2_scores  factor3_scores  factor4_scores
3   8   0   2
15  0   0   0

7   0   0   0
4   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
10  0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
13  7   0   4
0   0   0   0
3   1   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   1   2
4   1   0   4
34  0   2   4
3   0   0   0
13  5   0   0
0   0   0   0
13  0   0   2
1   0   0   5
0   1   2   0
21  0   0   0
0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0
20  2   0   2
5   0   0   0
22  0   2   1
24  0   1   1
13  5   3   0
13  0   0   2
1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   2   0   0
33  0   0   4
6   2   0   0
6   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0
0   1   0   0
5   0   2   0
1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0

0   0   0   2
3   0   0   0
12  0   0   4
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
19  8   5   0
31  0   4   2
0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0
23  1   2   1
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
33  0   0   0
0   2   0   0
13  1   0   0
3   0   0   1
1   0   0   0
41  5   1   0
0   0   0   0
5   2   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0
17  1   0   0
2   0   0   0
0   1   0   0
1   2   0   0
0   0   0   0
19  2   0   2
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
7   5   2   0
6   0   1   1
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0
5   0   0   0
2   0   0   0
0   0   0   1
14  0   0   1
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   1
1   0   0   0
23  1   3   0
3   0   0   0
4   0   0   0

1   0   0   1
4   0   0   0
11  0   1   0
15  0   0   2
0   0   0   0
20  0   0   0
0   0   0   0
41  0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
13  3   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   4   0   0
20  7   2   2
0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0
0   0   0   2
5   7   1   2
4   4   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0
3   0   0   0
0   0   0   2
6   1   2   0
0   3   0   0
25  0   0   0
12  0   0   0
8   1   1   0
11  0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0
0   0   9   5
22  2   0   0
0   0   0   0
21  0   0   3
4   3   0   0
16  0   0   0
0   0   0   0
6   2   2   0
0   0   0   0
7   0   0   2
1   0   0   3
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
44  8   4   0
13  0   0   0
0   0   0   0
18  3   6   0
1   0   0   0
13  2   2   2
5   1   2   0
22  0   0   1
0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0
12  0   1   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   2
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
37  3   3   0
1   1   0   0
19  2   0   0
2   0   0   0
24  0   0   1
1   2   0   0
5   0   0   0
7   0   0   0
2   0   0   2
39  6   3   3
12  3   0   0
14  0   0   0
2   0   0   4
0   2   0   0
0   0   0   2
0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0
0   1   0   0
1   0   0   0
1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0
13  0   0   4
0   0   0   0
1   2   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
32  0   0   2
4   0   1   0
10  0   0   0
3   0   0   0
9   1   2   0
0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0
7   0   0   0
0   1   0   0
5   1   0   0
15  1   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   1
5   0   0   0
0   0   0   2
27  7   0   0
0   0   0   0
18  2   0   0
0   3   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0
15  0   0   0
4   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
8   0   0   0
44  4   19  0
0   1   2   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
1   0   0   2
18  1   0   3
11  9   0   6
11  1   0   1
0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0
31  6   5   0
7   10  3   0
0   6   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0
3   0   0   0
0   1   0   0
23  2   0   0
0   0   0   0
1   3   0   2
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
17  1   0   1
28  1   0   0
27  0   0   3
0   0   0   0
11  1   0   2
14  0   1   1
0   0   0   0
39  9   4   0
0   0   0   2
0   0   0   0
12  2   0   0
25  1   2   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
7   0   0   1
0   0   0   3
3   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
5   0   2   0
0   0   0   0
24  0   0   0
2   0   0   0
29  2   0   0
13  2   11  3
8   0   0   0
18  0   0   0
6   7   0   4
0   0   0   1
2   6   3   4
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   3
0   0   0   0
37  7   0   18
24  0   0   0
0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0
6   4   3   0

8   0   0   1
0   0   0   0
35  2   0   2
3   2   0   0
10  0   2   0
0   0   0   0
0   6   0   0
3   0   0   3
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
17  0   1   1
12  0   0   0
0   0   0   0
46  7   0   5
12  5   0   3
0   1   0   0
7   0   0   0
0   2   0   0
12  0   0   0
3   0   0   0
3   1   0   0
36  0   0   0
18  0   0   2
7   0   0   0
25  4   0   0
3   2   0   0
3   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
11  0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0
46  0   0   0
3   0   0   0
7   0   0   3
7   0   1   0
38  7   1   1
11  1   0   0
0   0   0   0
10  0   0   1
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
11  0   0   0
24  0   0   0
3   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
8   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   2
0   0   0   0
7   0   0   3
34  0   0   1
16  0   0   3
5   2   0   0
5   0   0   0
26  3   4   4
0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0
43  0   0   0
0   0   0   5
13  10  3   2
0   0   0   0
15  2   1   4
19  0   0   0
8   0   0   0
4   4   0   0
0   0   0   3
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0

11  2   0   2
31  5   0   4
0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0
1   0   0   0
10  0   0   0
7   0   0   3
38  8   4   4
1   1   2   0
18  1   0   0
28  0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0
0   0   0   0
8   0   0   0
14  0   2   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0
0   1   0   0
0   0   0   0
2   1   0   2
6   0   0   2
16  1   2   0
23  0   0   0
1   0   0   0
0   0   0   3
2   0   0   0
50  3   0   0
7   0   0   0
29  0   5   2
1   0   0   0
0   3   0   0
0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0
8   0   1   0
0   0   0   0
7   0   0   0
1   8   0   0
0   0   0   0
32  0   18  2
10  2   0   0
2   0   0   0
26  0   1   0
3   2   0   1
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
5   0   0   2
19  0   0   0
28  2   3   4
0   1   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
15  0   1   0
0   1   0   0
0   0   0   2
0   0   0   0
12  2   0   0
0   1   0   0
20  0   2   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
16  0   0   2
10  0   0   0
1   1   0   1
25  3   3   2

0   0   0   0
13  2   0   0
1   0   0   0
0   0   0   1
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
2   0   0   3
39  2   2   2
1   0   0   0
8   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
3   0   0   1
0   0   0   0
0   1   0   2
0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0
3   0   0   0
20  0   0   0
42  1   1   3
1   0   0   0
21  0   0   1
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0
10  0   0   0
0   0   0   0
19  4   4   4
0   0   0   2
19  0   0   2
3   0   0   1
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
5   3   0   2
11  0   0   0
2   0   0   0
8   0   1   2
0   0   0   0
1   1   0   1
0   0   0   0
20  5   2   0
0   2   0   0
0   0   3   0
1   1   0   1
29  0   0   0
5   2   1   0
0   13  2   0
31  0   10  2
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0
2   0   2   0
29  2   0   2
6   0   0   0
3   2   2   0
32  2   2   0
15  0   0   3
11  2   0   3
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
14  2   0   2
0   0   0   0
2   0   1   0
0   0   0   2
56  0   0   2
14  0   1   3
0   0   0   0
3   1   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   2   0   2
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
44  1   0   3
1   2   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   4
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   3   0   4
2   4   6   0
16  0   0   0
42  0   2   3
0   0   0   0
0   4   0   1
18  0   0   2
0   0   0   2
2   0   0   0
10  0   0   0
41  4   0   0
0   1   0   0
6   1   0   2
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
8   0   0   0
22  0   2   0
31  0   0   0
0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0
14  1   0   2
4   13  0   4
16  4   2   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0

0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
16  0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
9   0   0   0
34  0   0   0
12  3   0   0

4   0   0   1
12  0   0   0
0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
45  4   5   2
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
37  5   6   1
18  0   0   2
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
2   0   0   2
3   0   0   2

15  3   2   0
19  5   2   4
30  0   0   0
4   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   2
0   5   0   0
0   0   0   0

0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   2   0   0
3   0   0   0
40  0   1   0
0   0   0   0
20  0   0   0
21  14  0   4
5   0   0   1
0   0   0   0
25  2   0   2
14  1   0   2
4   0   0   0
5   2   0   0
0   0   0   2
0   0   0   0
0   5   2   0
2   0   0   0
0   0   1   0
7   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
27  0   0   2
0   0   0   0
10  3   2   0
5   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   4   0   0
1   0   0   1
8   3   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   2   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   2   0   2
11  5   1   2
0   1   0   0
0   0   0   0
15  0   0   4
0   3   0   0
0   0   0   0
24  0   0   3
0   0   0   0
1   1   0   3
0   0   0   0
12  1   0   0
17  4   2   2
4   0   1   0
0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0
7   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
49  4   0   0
22  0   0   0
6   2   0   0
4   0   2   0
0   0   0   0
5   0   0   0
27  0   0   0
7   0   0   0
4   2   0   0
19  0   0   2
0   0   0   0
13  0   0   1
26  11  11  5
2   1   2   0
21  1   0   0
6   0   1   0
3   1   0   0
0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0
4   0   0   2
17  0   0   2
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
4   1   0   0
5   0   0   0
13  4   0   0
22  0   1   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
33  1   0   1
6   0   0   0
38  0   0   1
0   0   0   0
7   3   1   0
3   0   0   0
0   0   0   1
1   0   6   0
0   2   0   0
0   1   0   0
36  0   0   0
13  2   0   0
0   0   0   0
15  3   0   3
4   0   0   2
3   4   3   2
2   0   0   0

0   7   4   0
1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
19  0   0   0
0   2   0   0

1   2   0   2
0   0   0   0
6   0   0   0
8   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   1   0   2
1   0   0   2
0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0
9   0   0   0
2   0   0   0
8   0   0   1
0   0   0   0
4   4   3   3
0   0   0   0
0   1   1   0
0   0   0   0
31  2   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   2
47  8   4   2
0   0   0   0
5   5   0   0
1   0   0   0
8   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0
3   3   0   4
4   0   0   3
15  0   0   0
6   0   0   0
17  0   0   0
33  0   3   2
3   6   4   0
22  0   2   0
0   1   0   2
5   5   0   0
0   1   0   0
0   4   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   3   0   0
1   0   1   2
15  1   0   0
28  0   0   0
0   0   0   0
6   0   0   0

0   0   0   0
3   0   1   0
4   3   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   3   0   0
29  2   2   3
1   0   0   0
0   1   0   0
0   0   0   0
5   0   0   0
0   2   0   1
25  6   1   0
0   6   1   4
40  11  2   0
0   1   0   0
39  0   2   2
3   0   0   0
16  4   2   0
4   1   1   3
34  1   0   0
7   0   1   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   1
0   0   0   0
0   11  0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0
9   0   0   0
10  3   0   0
0   0   0   0
26  1   2   0
20  1   0   3
18  0   0   3
1   0   0   0
24  0   2   0
0   1   0   0
11  0   0   0
0   2   0   0
2   2   0   1
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
2   0   4   1
0   0   1   1
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0

0   0   3   0
0   0   0   3
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   2   0   0
19  0   0   0
6   0   0   0
12  2   0   0
0   0   0   2
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
5   2   0   1
41  6   6   4
1   0   0   1
4   0   0   0
11  0   2   1
4   0   0   0
45  4   0   0
4   4   1   0
15  0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
6   0   0   0
0   0   0   2
0   0   0   0
0   8   0   0
0   3   0   0
0   0   0   0
19  8   2   0
0   0   0   2
2   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
11  0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
5   3   1   4
15  0   0   0
0   0   0   2
6   0   0   0
0   0   0   1
4   0   0   0
0   0   1   0
33  4   2   0
61  3   0   5
0   0   1   0
0   0   0   0
2   0   0   2
12  0   0   0
0   1   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
1   0   1   0
0   0   0   1
0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0
3   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   2
0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0
0   2   0   2
22  4   0   2
8   5   4   3
25  1   0   0
0   2   0   0
15  0   0   3
7   1   0   0
15  0   0   0
4   2   0   0
33  0   4   2
13  2   0   4
4   0   0   0
25  0   2   2
6   0   0   0
1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   4
1   0   0   0
3   0   0   0
4   8   1   0
4   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   4
16  4   0   2
0   0   0   0
11  1   0   0
0   0   0   0
14  2   0   0
11  2   0   0
0   0   0   0
36  3   2   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   3
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
9   3   0   2
0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0
0   5   4   3
0   0   0   0
0   3   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
23  1   2   3
0   0   0   0
8   2   0   0
5   0   0   0
21  0   0   0
6   0   1   0
0   0   0   0
8   0   0   0
8   1   0   0
0   0   0   0
6   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
17  13  0   0
0   0   0   2
17  0   0   0
0   0   0   0
6   0   0   0
4   0   0   0
2   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
24  2   0   0
3   1   2   0
0   1   0   1
0   0   0   2
9   0   2   0
4   2   2   3
20  0   3   0
5   0   0   2
0   2   0   0
1   0   0   0
8   0   0   0
2   8   0   0
5   0   0   0
0   2   0   0
33  4   0   0
3   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
24  0   0   0
29  0   2   2
18  0   2   0
0   0   0   0
15  2   0   2
18  7   0   4
0   0   0   0
15  2   1   0
10  0   3   0
0   0   0   0
7   2   0   0
0   0   0   0
11  0   1   0
8   0   0   0
3   0   2   0
36  0   0   2
9   0   0   3
0   0   0   0
2   0   0   3
3   0   0   2
0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
3   0   2   1
0   0   0   0
4   0   1   1
4   0   0   0

0   0   0   0
8   5   3   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
2   4   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
12  7   2   1
10  0   0   0
0   0   0   0
1   0   2   0
0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
45  0   2   3
2   2   1   2
12  1   0   2
3   1   1   0
0   3   0   0
0   7   1   2
4   0   0   0
21  1   0   0
56  9   3   2
7   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
9   3   2   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   3
0   0   0   0
31  8   3   2
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
29  0   2   2
11  4   2   4
34  5   1   2
0   0   0   2
2   2   0   2
0   0   0   0
2   2   3   4
10  1   0   0
15  0   0   0
3   0   9   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0
0   0   0   0
6   0   0   0
4   0   0   0
24  3   3   2
7   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
2   0   0   3
0   0   0   2
0   0   0   0
17  0   2   3
16  1   4   0
0   0   0   0
30  3   1   0
6   0   0   0
3   7   0   2
0   0   0   0
16  0   0   0
21  2   0   1
0   0   0   0
16  8   4   5
0   0   0   2
13  1   0   1
34  0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
6   2   0   1
0   0   0   0
9   1   0   0
0   0   0   1
5   0   0   0
19  0   3   1

20  3   0   3
14  6   0   0
0   0   0   0
33  1   0   0
14  0   0   0

24  2   2   3
0   8   4   1
24  7   4   0
0   4   0   6
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
23  1   0   2
0   0   0   0
24  2   2   0
14  3   0   1
8   0   0   0
0   0   0   1
0   0   0   0
3   4   0   0
6   1   2   0
22  0   0   0
6   1   0   0
1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
16  3   0   0
0   0   0   0
6   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
3   4   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
26  0   2   2
1   0   0   0
3   0   0   1
1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
1   3   0   0
0   0   0   4
7       0   0
1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
14  2   0   2
0   1   0   1
9   2   0   0
0   0   0   0
4   3   2   2
12  4   0   0
3   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   6   1   0
0   0   0   2
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
6   2   0   0
0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0
17  2   0   0
0   2   0   3
1   0   0   0
19  0   0   0
3   3   2   0
16  0   1   0
8   4   4   1
0   0   0   0
12  0   0   3
1   0   0   2
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
5   5   0   0
0   0   0   0
22  10  0   0
0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0
1   0   3   0
0   0   0   0
0   5   0   0
0   2   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   2   0   0
3   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
5   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
5   2   0   0
0   0   0   0
33  1   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   1   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
4   2   0   0
14  0   0   3
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
20  0   0   3

4   0   0   0
4   0   2   0

0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
6   3   0   0
11  0   0   0
1   0   0   2
0   1   0   0
4   0   0   0
41  0   3   2
29  0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   2
15  0   0   2
32  10  2   0
10  2   0   3
0   7   2   0
23  2   0   0
3   2   0   0
40  3   0   2
22  1   0   0
30  6   0   2
11  0   0   1
0   3   0   0
0   0   1   1
0   2   0   0
0   0   0   0
12  2   3   2
16  1   0   3
11  0   0   0
2   1   2   0
0   1   0   0
14  0   0   0
5   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
33  1   4   0
1   3   0   0
40  5   0   3
42  3   1   0
0   0   0   0
5   0   0   0
14  0   0   0
0   0   0   0
17  0   0   0
17  0   0   0
0   0   0   0
13  7   3   0
2   1   0   0
4   0   0   1
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
12  1   0   0
0   0   0   0
2   0   1   1
3   0   0   0
4   0   0   2
0   0   0   2
0   0   0   0
11  2   0   0
0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0
14  4   0   0
5   0   0   0
0   0   2   1
3   0   0   0
15  0   0   5
0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0
42  0   0   0
5   0   2   0
14  3   0   2
5   2   1   0
17  2   0   1
8   2   0   0
0   5   3   0
0   0   0   0
0   4   0   0
10  0   0   0
11  0   0   2

0   0   0   1
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   3   0   0
13  0   0   0
0   0   0   0
6   5   0   0
8   0   0   2
0   0   0   1
1   0   0   0
4   2   0   0
10  9   3   2
54  3   3   2
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
4   2   0   0
3   0   0   0
0   0   5   0
3   0   0   1
0   0   0   0
21  1   0   1
9   3   0   0
0   1   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
15  0   1   0
0   0   0   0
6   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
3   0   0   2
0   7   0   0
22  6   0   0
0   4   0   0
3   0   0   1
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
22  1   5   2
0   0   0   2
0   0   0   0
12  0   2   2
25  0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   2   0   4
0   1   0   0

0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
7   2   0   0
3   0   0   0
27  9   4   2
28  8   3   0
0   1   0   0
0   0   0   0
3   0   1   2
17  0   0   1
1   0   0   0
4   0   0   0
3   4   0   0
1   2   2   2
0   0   0   0
16  0   0   0
8   0   0   1
    6   1    
0   0   0   0
22  0   0   3
0   3   1   1
0   1   4   1
9   3   0   0
0   0   1   0
1   0   0   1
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
1   3   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
42  2   0   0
1   0   1   0
1   0   0   0
12  0   0   1
0   0   0   4
41  3   1   0

3   7   2   0
0   0   0   0
30  2   0   1
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   2   0   0
0   0   0   2
0   0   0   0

0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   3   0   0

6   3   2   0
2   0   0   0
18  2   0   0
0   0   0   0
36  0   2   1
3   4   0   0

0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0
0   0   1   0
9   0   0   3
5   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
24  6   0   0

19  1   0   4
0   0   0   0
25  8   4   2
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   5   2   0
0   0   0   0
11  7   0   4
6   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
13  0   0   1
0   0   0   0
38  1   2   0
9   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
14  0   0   2
48  6   20  3
33  8   0   0
6   0   2   3
3   2   0   2
18  1   0   0
5   0   0   0
0   0   0   2
0   2   0   0
23  3   0   0
0   1   0   0
0   0   0   0
9   0   0   0
0   4   0   0
0   3   0   0
12  0   0   0
0   0   0   0
7   0   0   2
26  0   0   0
16  1   2   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   5   0   0
3   2   0   2
0   1   0   0
42  6   4   2
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   2
10  1   2   0
3   1   0   0
0   2   1   0
0   0   0   0
3   0   0   2
1   2   0   0
22  0   0   1
44  6   3   5
0   2   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   2

21  2   1   5
24  0   0   0
19  0   0   1
15  4   0   0
12  0   0   0
        18  0
0   2   0   2
25  3   0   4
10  8   0   0
11  5   5   0
6   1   0   0
15  1   0   4
0   3   0   0
42  0   0   0
4   3   0   0
5   4   0   0
11  0   0   0
17  0   0   0
0   0   0   0
7   5   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   4   3   0
41  7   3   4
0   0   0   0
0   1   0   2
7   6   1   2
0   0   0   0
15  2   2   4
6   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
43  12  0   0
0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0
7   4   0   2
0   2   0   0
20  0   0   0
15  4   4   0
0   13  1   0
0   0   0   0
5   0   0   1
1   2   2   1

0   0   0   0
10  0   0   0
0   2   0   2
37  4   5   4
6   4   1   3
1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   2   0   6
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0
4   2   3   0
4   0   0   1
15  8   0   0
17  3   1   0
0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0
5   0   0   0
41  1   1   3
18  3   0   4
26  8   6   0
0   0   0   0
21  1   1   0
9   5   2   0
0   1   0   0
0   0   0   0
3   0   0   2
4   0   3   0
41  3   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   3   2   0
9   2   0   0
3   0   0   0
1   3   9   0
2   2   0   0
0   0   0   0
29  2   0   1
3   0   0   0
0   1   0   0
1   0   0   2
19  4   0   4
18  0   0   0
1   0   0   0
24  0   0   3
0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0
9   3   0   0
17  0   0   1
10  7   4   4
0   0   0   0
20  0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
11  0   3   5
4   0   0   0


14  0   0   0

9   0   0   2
0   0   0   0
18  1   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   1
0   0   0   0
21  0   1   0
34  4   0   1
6   0   0   0
6   4   0   0
2   0   1   0
0   0   0   0
10  3   0   0
0   0   0   0
7   2   0   3
0   0   0   0
6   0   0   0
0   0   1   0
8   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
14  0   0   0
18  3   0   4
0   3   0   0
43  10  4   1
0   0   0   0
4   10  3   0
0   0   0   0
24  13  5   6
6   4   0   0
12  0   0   0
30  0   3   2
2   0   0   0
0   0   0   1
4   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
11  0   0   0
0   0   0   0
15  3   5   2
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
5   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
12  0   0   0
19  0   0   0
3   2   0   0
18  6   3   0
8   0   0   0
0   0   0   4
17  0   0   0
0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0
4   0   2   3
0   0   0   0
1   3   0   0
5   0   0   0
11  2   0   4
6   0   0   0
5   3   0   2
0   0   0   0
17  5   0   0
0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0
16  0   0   0

18  0   0   3
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0
32  0   2   4
2   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   2
11  0   0   0
4   0   0   0
0   1   0   0
24  4   2   0
3   0   0   0
17  3   2   1
2   2   2   0
2   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   1
38  2   2   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
40  2   0   4
0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0
0   1   0   0
6   0   0   0
0   0   0   1
11  2   0   3
4   1   0   0
25  0   0   0
43  0   0   0
0   0   0   0
1   0   0   9
0   0   0   0
1   2   0   0
1   2   0   0

12  4   0   1
43  5   2   5
18  2   1   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
3   2   0   0
0   0   0   0
44  2   4   2
1   4   0   2
3   3   0   0
0   0   0   0
35  0   0   2
1   0   0   0
4   0   0   0
3   2   0   0
0   0   1   0
16  3   0   2
0   0   0   0
7   0   2   0
0   0   0   0
35  5   0   1
20  0   0   0
6   0   0   0
2   3   0   2
1   0   0   2
4   0   0   0
0   5   0   0
1   1   0   3
3   0   0   0
10  0   0   0
0   2   0   0
0   0   0   0
9   0   0   1
0   0   0   0
37  0   0   2
2   0   0   0
3   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
11  0   0   0
22  0   1   0
38  0   1   1
19  0   0   3
2   1   0   2
18  10  4   1
17  5   3   3
19  4   0   0
8   5   4   4
14  0   3   2
1   0   0   0
35  6   2   0
24  2   0   0
7   1   0   0
5   0   0   0
7   3   0   2
0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0

0   0   0   0
0   5   0   0
20  0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
10  0   0   0
0   8   0   4

3   4   0   0
0   0   0   0
15  4   0   2
0   1   0   3
16  0   0   2
3   2   0   0
34  6   2   4
8   1   0   0
16  0   0   0
0   0   0   0
1   1   4   4
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
38  0   2   0
0   2   1   0
0   0   0   0
5   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
18  0   0   1
11  0   0   2
0   0   0   0
7   0   0   2

7   0   0   0
0   2   0   0
6   3   0   0
1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0
1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
2   1   0   0
0   0   0   0
6   2   1   2
24  0   0   2
0   0   0   0
18  0   0   0
0   0   0   0
22  2   0   0
2   0   0   0
8   0   1   0
0   0   0   0
30  0   2   0
3   0   0   2
0   0   0   0
10  3   3   0
0   0   0   0
34  0   2   3
0   0   2   0
15  0   0   4
3   0   1   0
10  0   0   3
0   0   0   0
1   0   0   2
13  0   0   0

1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
10  0   0   0
10  1   0   2
0   0   0   0
23  2   4   2
3   2   0   0
11  0   0   0
4   0   3   0
5   1   0   1
16  0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   1   0
13  1   0   2
6   1   0   0
0   0   0   0
19  0   0   2
13  0   0   0
17  0   0   0
11  0   2   0
0   0   0   0
4   0   0   2
4   2   0   0
3   0   0   0
11  0   0   0
0   0   0   3
0   0   0   0
0   2   0   0
0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0
20  8   3   4
3   0   0   0
0   2   0   1
17  1   1   0
38  5   0   0
0   0   0   0
8   0   0   0
4   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0
11  0   0   0
0   0   0   3
0   0   0   0
24  7   0   5
0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0
9   0   3   0
0   7   0   0
1   9   3   0
0   1   0   2
0   0   0   0
36  0   2   1
3   0   0   0
8   1   2   2
0   0   0   0
24  0   0   2
0   1   0   0

39  9   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0
0   10  0   0
10  0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0
0   2   0   0
0   3   4   0
3   0   0   0
0   0   0   0

8   1   1   0
15  0   0   0
0   4   0   0
1   0   0   1
0   0   0   0
2   0   1   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
22  0   0   0
9   2   4   3
3   1   0   1
0   0   0   0
12  0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0
3   0   0   0
8   0   0   0
5   2   4   5
1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   2
0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0
0   1   1   0
38  1   1   3
9   0   0   0
2   0   0   0
4   4   1   0
6   2   0   2

0   3   0   0
1   0   0   0
17  2   1   0
0   0   2   2
0   5   0   0
28  6   2   0
0   1   0   0

0   0   0   0
30  9   4   3
3   0   0   0

6   0   3   0
8   0   0   0
4   2   0   0
0   5   0   0
0   1   0   0
9   0   0   0
51  9   0   0
20  3   0   1
0   0   0   0
5   0   0   0
4   0   0   1
6   1   0   0
30  0   1   0
16  0   0   0
3   0   0   0
```

Comment: If you aren't told what method of factor analysis was used, there is now way to answer this question. It could very well be hand coded factors leading to integer scores. Also, if you have categorical data, factor analysis in itself will be largely useless as correlation between dummy variables isn't really reliable.

Comment: @ArunJose It is the method to compute the factor scores which is unknown. I added a description of the factor analysis itself.

Comment: That's my point, if you don't know which method, then how are you to know what generated integer scores?

Comment: Are they many ways to generate integer scores? I could not actually find even one. These scores would likely have been generated by the Mplus software (I added this info to the question).

Comment: They are most likely hand coded features based on knowledge of the survey design. Pca and factor analysis are two types by the way

Comment: What do you mean "hand coded"? Factor scores are computed by fitting the model to the data according to specific algorithms (e.g. regression based weights, weights such that the factor scores will be uncorrelated, etc.). This is done AFTER the factor analysis has been performed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59223/discussion-between-michael-and-arun-jose).

Comment: You should get to the formulas how the program computes these factor scores. Factor scores are computed with binary/categorical data differently than in classic FA. If you've got an answer to your question since you published it, please mind posting an answer - it might be very instructive.